# How to setup CloudFront to have a custom error page per origin

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to deploy an Angular Application on AWS using S3 and Cloudfront. Our Angular App is communicating on a Spring application serving as our backend app that is residing on an EC2 instance. I have already configured our CloudFront to redirect `/api` requests to our backend and everything else to the frontend. Right now, I've setup Cloudfront's custom error response for 403 and 404's to return our angular's index.html. **The problem is that** when our fontend tries to send and API call to our backend and returns a 404 with a valid json response, instead of receiving the json. We get the index.html file.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the user accesses http://somedomain.com/invalid-path, they get served with the index.html but if they try to API call to  http://somedomian.com/api/v1/invalid-path they should get what the back-end server returns.

Comment: Disappointing on how CloudFront does not allow creating redirection rules to supersede that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create Lambda Function Association of Event type `Origin response` to modify the status code and body content. You will want to add this in the CloudFront `behaviors` used for your front-end app. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-custom-error-static-body) is the example.

You can add 302 header and redirect to a location (cache behavior) for static error page or you can attach content to `response.body` and change status code to 200.

[More on Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html)

Comment: Accepting this answer as this is one way to do it but what I've come up is entirely different. I've set up my S3 bucket as a website endpoint and set the error handling there before adding it on Cloudfront as a custom origin.

Comment: @ChUck_PrOg could you add your solution as an answer as well (with some more info)? thanks

Comment: Careful - this, as any solutions involving Lambda@Edge, will not work in the China regions.

Answer (score 12):

I had same problem and solved as follows:

- Configure the S3 bucket to have 'Static website hosting' and set index.html as the 'Error document'.
- Change the CloudFront origin to be a 'Custom Origin' pointing to the S3 static website endpoint rather than an 'S3 Origin' pointing directly at the S3 bucket.
- The 'Error Pages' config can then be removed from the CloudFront distribution.

Comment: A note about this solution: the S3 Bucket must be public.  This may not be an issue for most people, but if you're trying to set something up where the bucket is only accessible via CloudFront, this won't work.

Comment: This also doesn't work if you host multiple cloudfronts in a single bucket.

Comment: I decided to exclude the error pages config at all like you mentioned, but I'm not sure if I follow your solution. Where exactly do you map the errors? I have a 401.html and a 404.html for example, how can I redirect correctly to each html page?
My original idea was to do that on a lambda@edge, but apparently I can't modify the body in a lambda@edge.

Comment: @AndréSilva in my case I'm hosting a React SPA and in S3 both the Index and Error documents are set to index.html. i.e., the SPA renders error pages as appropriate - there is no separate 401.html or 404.html. S3 only allows a single Error document to be specified. So, if you want specific error pages, S3 static website hosting may be too basic for you.

Comment: You shouldn't do this anymore.  If the site is hosted with Cloudfront you need to add Origin access control settings to the Origin, disable static website hosting, disallow public access and update the bucket policy.

Comment: @BryanC. how does your suggestion solve the original problem? And why is this a problem if it's okay for the S3 bucket to be public? Genuinely interested as I'm still using this solution and can't see the Lambda solution as worth the complexity in my case.

Comment: Cloudfront has functions in NodeJS that it runs @Edge. 
It looks like they are trying to reverse proxy the content at the /api/v1/ location. So for that Cloudfront is good. See here: https://alukach.com/posts/using-cloudfont-as-a-reverse-proxy/

Comment: @BryanC. I don't understand, the link you provided details using the same solution as mine: https://alukach.com/posts/using-cloudfont-as-a-reverse-proxy/#single-page-applications. The Lambda solution is more complex, and I'd think only required if the S3 bucket can't be public.